# Force field destroys particle rotation

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

Newtonian type emitter is using explode modifier to manipulate faces. Problem is when I put Vortex field on the same layer as emitter, my particles stop rotating, even if field strength is set to zero. But keeping them on different layers bring rotation back (but without effect of force). How to use it properly?

**With zero force on the same layer**
[image]

**And on separate layers**
[image]

[image]

**EDIT:** Max distance in Falloff settings allows particles to rotate outside force area (circle dot line), but it still stops inside.

[image]

Comment: Try enabling at least Rotation in the Effect Point group in the force field options and then Minimum and Maximum values in Faloff group there below as most likely you want force field to enable differently in different points of space.

Comment: Enabling Rotation doesn't help really. Particles loose theirs random orientation inside force field and rotate in according with radial direction of vortex. Noise value also doesn't do much difference.

Comment: Set the Power and Strength values back to their default values at least, at 0 you won't get any expected effect. Noise has nothing to do with this case.

Comment: Of course, I've set it back to some significant amount, but here you can see results: https://imgur.com/a/THJI3

Comment: I doubt you can anything do with one particle system for including both random rotation and [force one as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA9bo.gif), after all when force affects it adds acceleration when particle loses its own rotation due to speed. Although it might not and then one solution is to [add another force field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjL68.gif) of e.g. Turbulence type (or add Self Effect to particles of that type) and make them additionally rotate